# PHP Error: Class 'Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Admin' [Laravel 8]

Tags: php, laravel, tinker, laravel-8

I have issues with the php error when I tried to insert data for admin using the tinker. I'm creating a multi authentication user which is one for user and one for admin.

> PHP Error:  Class 'Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/Admin' not found in c:/S/htdocs/i-V/app/Models/Admin.php on line 13

How do I resolve that error?

`Admin`

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\AdminResetPasswordNotification;


class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'admin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

[image]

I have tried to remove the composer.lock file then install it again
also I have done this.

```
composer dump-autoload
composer install --no-scripts
composer update
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Change this**

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Admin as Authenticatable;`

to

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;`

as `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` it is core code from laravel core  and it don't have `Admin` class

Comment: Oh I didn't know that!. Thank you for explaining it works. So even thought we are creating another level of authentication so we only need to use this `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User` right? Thank you.

Comment: @lily please mark this as answer so other will not spend time on this